# Error: 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I am trying to get the users info after user enters email and password. The api i am using returns me user's extra informations so i am trying to get that info as a start.

I am trying to parse this json:

```
[
    {
        "_user": {
            "id": "id-here",
            "name": "Mobile",
            "email": "mobile.user@asd.com",
            "photo": null,
            "title": null,
            "surname": "User",
            "bg_photo": null,
            "isactive": true,
            "password": "123456789",
            "username": "mobileuser",
            "checkInfo": true,
            "role_type": "asd",
            "profession": null,
            "isemailverify": false
        },
        "tokens": {
            "accessToken": "someTokenhere",
            "refreshToken": "anotherOne"
        }
    }
]
```

These are my models:

```
class User {
  User({
    this.user,
    this.tokens,
  });

  UserClass user;
  Tokens tokens;

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){
    return User(
      user: UserClass.fromJson(json["_user"]),
      tokens: Tokens.fromJson(json["tokens"]),
    );
  }
}

class Tokens {
  Tokens({
    this.accessToken,
    this.refreshToken,
  });

  String accessToken;
  String refreshToken;

  factory Tokens.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tokens(
    accessToken: json["accessToken"],
    refreshToken: json["refreshToken"],
  );
}

class UserClass {
  UserClass({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.email,
    this.photo,
    this.title,
    this.surname,
    this.bgPhoto,
    this.isactive,
    this.password,
    this.username,
    this.checkInfo,
    this.roleType,
    this.profession,
    this.isemailverify,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String email;
  String photo;
  String title;
  String surname;
  String bgPhoto;
  bool isactive;
  String password;
  String username;
  bool checkInfo;
  String roleType;
  String profession;
  bool isemailverify;

  factory UserClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserClass(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    email: json["email"],
    photo: json["photo"],
    title: json["title"],
    surname: json["surname"],
    bgPhoto: json["bg_photo"],
    isactive: json["isactive"],
    password: json["password"],
    username: json["username"],
    checkInfo: json["checkInfo"],
    roleType: json["role_type"],
    profession: json["profession"],
    isemailverify: json["isemailverify"],
  );
}
```

This is the part that i send email, password and get user's data:

```
Future<User> checkUserExist(String email, String password) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.https('SomeApi', 'Route'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
        'email': email,
        'password': password
      }),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception(jsonDecode(response.body));
    }
  }
```

This is the part gives me error

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
}
```

I printed the response body it gives me what i want -the string- but jsonDecode returns a list so i cant use it. How can i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body))
```

To this:

```
return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0])
```

The reason is that you're doing everything perfectly, until the last step. If you look closely at your response, it does have a map or `_user` and `token`, but this map is actually inside a list, notice the square brackets `[ ]` around the `{}`.

The map that you need to access, is at index`[0]` of this list, then everything will work fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation it worked <3

Comment: You're most welcome! It happens a lot and is easy to miss. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return User.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body)[0]);
    }
```